# How to pass the Now() Function from one page to another in php

Tags: php, javascript

I am displaying the `timestamp=now()` from one page to another. How can I pass this function? As on the second page I want to retrieve the table on the basis of  `timestamp=now()`. I have done this but it's not working. Kindly help me in this.

Coding

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function showCustomer(n)
{
var xmlhttp;    

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  alert(n);
xmlhttp.open("POST","display.php?id="+ n,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form>
<?php $s= 'now()';
echo $s; ?>
<input type="button" value="h" name="s" onclick="showCustomer(<?php $s ?>)">
<div id='display' >
<?php 
echo "111";

?>
</div>
```

I retrieve the data from the database through this coding:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$sa="select * from table1 where timestamp=now()";
$result=mysql_query($sa) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
</tr>";?>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $row['c1'];
    $row['c2'];
    $row['c3'];
         $row['c4'];
}
```

I must call this table on button click on next page by also considering the Now() function. Kindly help me.

Comment: Please pass the now() as a GET parameter the same way you pass the ID.

Comment: string must be quoted in js

Comment: FYI: `mysql_` queries are deprecated and open to SQL injections. Use `mysqli` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to preserve some timestamp: use sessions for that

```
session_start();//in every file (in which you want to access sessions) as first statement before any output
//set time
$_SESSION['now'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //mysql datetime format
//read time
$save_time = $_SESSION['now'];
```

Comment: sir i need to to do changes in javascripting too

Comment: if thats a question, i would say: you can remove everything in the js that works on/with 'now' since you handle that via pure php with this code.

Comment: sir its not workng like ths as on clickng the button it want show any thng

Comment: `function showCustomer()`, `onclick="showCustomer();"`, `xmlhttp.open("POST","display.php",true);`, remove `<?php $s= 'now()';
echo $s; ?>` and `alert(n);`

Comment: on display page when i aceess this what is the query for acessing ths iused ths '<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php

include('config.php');

$sa="select * from table1 where  timestamp =now()";
$result=mysql_query($sa) or die(mysql_error());'

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `echo` in this statement `<input type="button" value="h" name="s" onclick="showCustomer(<?php $s ?>)">`.

Please! overwrite this line with `<input type="button" value="h" name="s" onclick="showCustomer(<?php echo $s ?>)">`

Comment: Yeah but only if he has enabled `short_open_tag=On` in php.ini file :-).

Comment: @nderscore it will work only if `short_tags` are opened otherwise will get errors

Answer (score 0):

There is no `php` NOW() function it is a `mysql`  function if you want the same values that mysql's `NOW()`   returns

You have to use php's `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` in this format here is the reference [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
<?php $s= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $s; ?>
```

Comment: sir i get the date in $s how can i pass this to javascripting